# How to calculate size of a GIF image?

Tags: java, android, size, gif

I want to convert my video 9 seconds to GIF. I choose the following parameters:

FPS: 7 , Scale: original (720x1152).
In the result I get a gif with size 4.67MB.

Can anybody show me how to guess size of gif depending on input parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If the gif has a BitDepth of 8 bit (256 color) then

```
(x * y * fps * length) / 8 = size in bytes
```

But gif uses compression so this is not always true.

Comment: In my case 720 * 1152 * 7 * 9 = 49.8 MB (for 256 color). The real size is 4.67MB. Is something wrong here?

Comment: Sorry it was in bits not bytes. Not it's corrected. But you can't calculate the compression size.